# Missing parser library (lxml) in Anaconda with Python

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, lxml

I've installed Anaconda and the modules for requests, bs4, lxml, selenium through pip.

When I do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml')
```

I get the error:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. 

Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I found a number of questions on this already, and here's what I've tried (but none have worked):

1. Uninstall/reinstall lxml
2. Download the whl file for lxml and load it manually (when I did this, it said that lxml was already satisfied)
3. `conda install -x auto htmlparser` (I got the error - `packagesnotfounderror: the following packages are not available from current channels`)
4. I've checked that my bs4 and lxml are fully upgraded

I'm not a programmer, so please keep that in mind in your responses, this is my first foray into the programming world. Thank you!

Comment: "I've installed Anaconda and the modules for requests, bs4, lxml, selenium through pip". Do you have a different Python env apart from the one that was shipped with Anaconda?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to install either of these packages with pip because these packages are available in `conda` channels. So `conda install lxml`, `conda install beautifulsoup4` and so on should have done the job and avoided any conflicts with existing Python package installs through `pip`.

Comment: @user8212173 I originally tried using IDLE but had trouble with it, so I switched over to Anaconda. Apart from installing the modules I've listed above, I haven't done anything else to it.

Comment: I did the conda instal lxml and it says that it worked. I rebooted and tried the same code again and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I also tried "from lxml import html" and it's telling me there's  a ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'lxml'

Comment: This is most likely the case when lxml is installed in a different env than the conda env. Are you able to import other packages, for example `import requests`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, able to solve it by uninstalling lxml from conda and install it with pip.

those are my packages when installing all with conda

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0
certifi                   2018.11.29               py37_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h74b6da3_1
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
cryptography              2.5              py37h7a1dbc1_0
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
libxslt                   1.1.33               h579f668_0
lxml                      4.3.1            py37h1350720_0
openssl                   1.1.1a               he774522_0
pip                       19.0.1                   py37_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0
python                    3.7.2                h8c8aaf0_2
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0
selenium                  3.141.0          py37he774522_0
setuptools                40.8.0                   py37_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
soupsieve                 1.7.1                    py37_0
sqlite                    3.26.0               he774522_0
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h21ff451_3    anaconda
vs2015_runtime            15.5.2                        3    anaconda
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py37_1
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
```

bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library

after uninstalling via conda and install via pip

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0
certifi                   2018.11.29               py37_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h74b6da3_1
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
cryptography              2.5              py37h7a1dbc1_0
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
libxslt                   1.1.33               h579f668_0
lxml                      4.3.1                     <pip>
openssl                   1.1.1a               he774522_0
pip                       19.0.1                   py37_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0
python                    3.7.2                h8c8aaf0_2
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0
selenium                  3.141.0          py37he774522_0
setuptools                40.8.0                   py37_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
soupsieve                 1.7.1                    py37_0
sqlite                    3.26.0               he774522_0
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h21ff451_3    anaconda
vs2015_runtime            15.5.2                        3    anaconda
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py37_1
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
```

Collecting lxml
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/9e/316022255a2b715b0efaa967aa89119544906b3ed4f5131c1c9b6962baca/lxml-4.3.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.3.1

works for me :)